# Return new collection without modifying original collection

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have a Laravel collection and I want to modify one of its property value to negative integer. For this I am using the collection `map` method but it also modifying the original collection.

My code:

```
$modified_revenue_data = $revenue_data->map(function ($item) {
    if ($item->is_claw_back == 1 && $item->claw_back_date != null) {
        return $item->revenue = $item->revenue * -1;
    }

    return $item;
});
```

I want to store the new collection into `$modified_revenue_data` but `$revenue_data` is also modified.

What would be the correct way of doing it without modifying the original collection?

Comment: by default, $collection->map() will update and return each new item, while the original collection items are unchanged. If you wish to mutate the original directly, consider using `$collection->transform(function ($item) { $item->field = 'new value'; return $item; });`. [example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/add-key-value-to-current-object-in-eloquent-collection)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't update the original collection:

```
$original = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$modified = $original->map(function ($el) {
     return $el * 2; 
});

dd($modified);
```

> ```
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3726
>      all: [
>        2,
>        4,
>        6,
>        8,
>        10,
>      ],
>    }
> ```

```
dd($original);
```

> ```
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3743
>      all: [
>        1,
>        2,
>        3,
>        4,
>        5,
>      ],
>    }
> ```

This behaviour is also stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map):

> ### map()
>
> ...
>
> Like most other collection methods, **map returns a new collection**
> instance; **it does not modify the collection it is called on.** If
> you want to transform the original collection, use the `transform()`
> method.

Comment: This is a single dimensional collection. I am facing problem in multi dimensional collection where I just want to change one of the property.

Comment: @FahadShaikh Should be the same. The resulting of the mapping should be stored in a newly created collection, not changing the previous one.

Comment: @DanCantir I'm not the OP, the one is Fahad Shaikh.

Comment: @KennyHorna oh sorry, my bad!

Comment: @KennyHorna your collection is not being modified. I don't know then why mine?

Comment: @FahadShaikh because Kenny Horna is using integer values, which are not passed by reference. I will update my answer.